# Binding failing for form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a webapi that is supposed to receive a file upload.
The general definition is:

```
[Route("/{rdmId}/files/{fileName}")]
public class RDMFilesController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new file for the given RDM. If the file already exists an error is returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PUT(string rdmId, string fileName, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
         // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

On the Do Stuff part, if you check, `file` is null. But if you check `Request.Form.Files[0]` the file is there!

What am I doing wrong? I was expecting that `file` to be populated...

**Edit 1:** the client side so far is a Postman following [this tutorial](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1441#issuecomment-289452571)

Comment: I am not sure `[FromForm]` and `HttpPut` fits together, if it is, check the client if there is an exact `file` object. It would be better to share the client side.

Comment: I tested with `HttpPost` but it presented the same behaviour

Comment: try IList<IFormFile> files  instead of [FromForm]IFormFile file make sure that your form  has   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">

Comment: Does `Request.Form.Files[0].Name == "file"`?

Comment: no, the file name is empty, but the content matches 100%!

Comment: @JohnMeek John, no luck using "IList", and my front end is not a webpage, it's a postman... the tutorial I used is linked on the question... but notice: the `Request.Form.Files[0]` is there! and OK!

Comment: it is also necessary to have the enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate `rdmId` and `fileName` arguments with `[FromRoute]` attribute like this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PUT([FromRoute]string rdmId, [FromRoute]string fileName, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
         // DO STUFF
    }
```

Also you should put `rdmId` and `fileName` in the route and send file as `Body` -> `form-data` in Postman with `key=file`.

[image]

Comment: didn't work... tried that already, all of those... followed that tutorial by the letter

Comment: check the modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Request.Form.Files[0].Name == "file"` is false, it will not bind. Without the names matching its not going to work. In Postman, make sure your `key` is set to "file".

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this, this will surely help you.

```
[Route("{rdmId}/files/{fileName}")]
public class RDMFilesController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new file for the given RDM. If the file already exists an error is returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PUT([BindRequired, FromRoute]string rdmId, [BindRequired, FromRoute]string fileName, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
         // DO STUFF
    }
}
```